# iOS Simulatorを多重起動する方法

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

Webアプリケーション開発時など、複数のiOS Simulatorで同時にテストしたいケースがあります。1台のMacで、複数のエミュレータを同時に起動する方法はあるでしょうか?

参考まで、手元で試した次の方法はいずれもうまく行きませんでした。2つ目のインスタンスを立ち上げようとすると、「Unable to boot device in current state: Booted」というエラーが出て、黒い画面だけが表示されます。

1) `open`コマンドで、`-n`オプションを指定する。

```
$ open -n -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app`
```

2) 別ユーザで、`open`コマンドを使う。

```
$ su OtherUser
$ open -n -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app`
```

[image: 2つめのインスタンス]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stackoverflow英語版のこの回答 https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717027/3474143?stw=2 が参考になると思います。

このアプリ http://www.coderebel.com/2010/08/31/iphone_simulator（実体は単なるシェルスクリプト）を使うと、複数セッションできるよう設定を変更した後、iPhoneSimulator を起動してくれ、ユーザ毎に個別の iPhoneSimulator を起動できるようになりました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。起動可能なことを確認しました!

最初、GUIでユーザ切替しないとうまく行かないので、おかしいな...と思ったのですが、openコマンドはFinderのユーザでアプリを起動してしまうんですね...。iOS Simulator内のパッケージ内の実行ファイルを直接起動すればOKでした。

Comment: 念のため、上記アプリを使わずに同じことをやってみたんですが、それでも起動しました。単に別ユーザで起動すればOKということのようでした。

Answer (score 4):

(解決が見つかったので、自己レスです)

openコマンドだと、別ユーザで起動できませんでした。別ユーザをGUIで作成した後、直接実行ファイルをsudoすることで、複数のiOS Simulatorを同時起動できました。

```
$ sudo -u <別ユーザ名> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iOS\ Simulator
```

[image: 複数起動したiOS Simulator]